# Setup a new startup job in Manjaro

Tags: systemd, cron, manjaro, systemctl

I have installed Manjaro Linux with `5.7.0-3-MANJARO` kernel. The problem is that every time I boot the system, I have to start my `NetworkManager` module manually with the command `sudo systemctl start NetworkManager`. I want my system to start it automatically. I tried adding it as a `cron` job with `crontab -e`, but it does not work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you edit into the question the output of `systemctl status NetworkManager` please from before you run the `start`?

Comment: @icarus, `inactive service`

Comment: If this is all the output from running the command, can you add the contents of /lib/systemd/sys/NetworkManager.service to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do **not** try to use cron for this !
  Cron is meant to run repeating tasks. If you try to do it with cron it will constantly run this command again (it doesn't do any *real* damage but that doesn't make it a good idea either
- Correct solution: `sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager`
  (The difference between `enable` and `start` is that `enable` will make sure that from that moment on it will always happen when the system is started)

Comment: Oh! Okay. Thanks :) Also, can you please tell me if Arch does not have an `init.d` by default or I have messed up the installation? From what I know, Arch is systemd, meaning init.d is a must